# Query when data is not available in one of the table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables A & B. I used left join on table, but when left table(A) does not have I want query which return right table values with same columns as blank from left table.

I used below query and it is working fine for me. Is there any better way to built same query to **improve performance**?

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM TableA WHERE Project_ID = @Project_ID)
    SELECT
        A.ID, A.Project_ID, A.Column1, A.Column2, 
        B.Column 
    FROM
        TableA A 
    LEFT JOIN
        TableB B ON A.Project_ID = B.Project_ID 
    WHERE
        A.Project_ID = @Project_ID
ELSE
    SELECT
        B.ID, B.Project_ID, '' As Column1, '' As Column2, B.Column 
    FROM
        TableB 
    WHERE
        project_ID = @Project_ID
```

Comment: What made you think the performance could be improved? And are you looking for faster or neater?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you want a `full join`:

```
select A.ID, A.Project_ID, A.Column1, A.Column2, B.Column
from (select a.*
      from TableA a
      where A.Project_ID = @Project_ID
     ) a full join 
     (select b.*
      from TableB b
      where b.Project_ID = @Project_ID
     ) b
     on a.Project_ID = b.Project_ID;
```

When filtering with `full join`s, I usually find it most sensible to use subqueries.

Comment: It was hard to quickly see the “full join” in this example to the placement.

Answer (score 1):

you should use full join:

```
SELECT
    ISNULL(A.ID,B.ID) AS ID
   ,ISNULL(A.Project_ID, B.Project_ID) AS Project_ID
   , A.Column1, A.Column2, B.Column 

FROM
    TableA A 

FULL JOIN
    TableB B ON A.Project_ID = B.Project_ID 

WHERE
    isnull(A.Project_ID ,B.Project_ID) =  @Project_ID
```